# Make a mobile device a remote control for a tablet?

Tags: android, ipad, mobile, bluetooth, wifi

I'm trying to make an app on an Android device that will control an application on an iPad or Android tablet. (I'm testing with an Samsung Galaxy S2 and an iPad 2).

The application is pretty simple for now. When one selects a colour on the Android mobile, that colour displays on the tablet device.

The question is, how to connect the two devices. Just now I've verified that I can pair the two devices using Bluetooth. Also, the Samsung has a "Kies" Wifi Direct feature (which I don't understand fully), that allows the iPad to connect to the Galaxy as a wifi hotspot.

The connections are there, but I don't know if either protocol can be used to actually get the apps to talk to each other to get the control I'm looking for.

Should I be using Bluetooth, Wifi, or something else?

And in whichever case, how?

Comment: Do you wish to have a direct connection between the two devices in a non existent wifi network situation, or indirect connections? I.E. you could both be connected to the same wifi (similar to how a boxee remote works) if you wish to have a indirect connection. Or as you've mentioned the pairing, that would be direct. Will the devices be of the same OS or could OS's get mixed? I.E. iPhone and Android Tablet, or vice versa?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My opinion is that you should not stick so much around the physical medium used for connectivity either is WiFi or Bluetooth. You should abstract this aspect, in both cases you will be using sockets (I'm speaking about Android), if it's Bluetooth you will be using Bluetooth Sockets, if it's WiFi: TCP sockets. You could have a intermediate layer that abstracts the type of connection and through a factory to use either Bluetooth or TCP.

Bluetooth - http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html

For WiFi you should study if P2P would help.

You will need two applications:
- one on the tablet - the server which listens for commands from the client (change color, do this or this)
- second on the smartphone - the client which sends commands.

Answer (score 5):

I've built a few apps that do exactly that between iPhone and iPad.  But the principle is the same. I used Bonjour networking. It's just a fancy name for ZeroConfig networking between devices. It's written originally by Apple but it's open source so there should be Android support out there for it too. Really simple and easy to work with.

Answer (score 4):

If you already have a working connection then you already have the first half of your answer, that said you should really consider implementing a solution that uses a variety of connection types, WIFI, Bluetooth, etc.. The question I think you are really asking is how to pass data and messages between the apps once you have the connection.

There are a lot of ways to accomplish this. You could implement your own lightweight message passing system. If you haven't done this before it is more complicated than it originally seems, especially as you would be required to implement the system for each OS you end up using.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I be using Bluetooth, Wifi, or something else?

It depends on what situations you want your program to work in.

Bluetooth can provide a direct connection between your devices. A potential issue with bluetooth is that it has a limited range. If you're devices need to be far away from each other, you may want to go with wifi. Otherwise, bluetooth could work great.

If both devices are connected to the internet, you can make them talk to each other through there. The advantage of this approach is that it doesn't matter how far apart your devices are as long as they're both online. A disadvantage is that you'll have to figure out how to find the tablet's ip address before you can talk to it. This is actually a HUGE disadvantage because it can be quite problematic if both of your devices are not on the same wifi. You could have the user type in the destination ip address, but you'll have problems getting it to work if the user is behind a router (which will almost always be the case). The point is, it gets hairy.

If both of your devices are on the same wifi, you can use ZeroConf AKA bonjour (like Dancreek said) to figure out what ip address you need to send info to. I've previously used a library called jmdns (easy to find with google) to implement zero configuration networking. It's good because the user doesn't have to worry about ip addresses... it's intuitive for the user.

> And in whichever case, how?

Networking is a pretty big topic, so I can't expand on this question to much. Short answer is, it depends on what method you choose. Search for some tutorials and start by getting one of your devices to send something as simple as an int to the other.